# how can I generate an SSH key with NodeJS that can be imported in PuTTY?

Tags: node.js, ssh, cryptography, putty

Trying to replace an old application that calls `ssh-keygen` and generates a new SSH Key.
We need to support both OpenSSH (Mac OS X and Ubuntu 14+ clients) and PuTTY (Windows clients).

With the availability fo the `crypto` module in NodeJS 10.x, I wrote the the little code below:

```
import crypto = require('crypto');

const generateKeyPairAsync = util.promisify(crypto.generateKeyPair);

export async function generateSshKeys(passphrase: string) {
    const keys = await generateKeyPairAsync('rsa', {
        modulusLength: 2048,
        privateKeyEncoding: {
            cipher: 'aes256',
            format: 'pem',
            passphrase,
            type: 'pkcs1',
        },
        publicKeyEncoding: {
            format: 'pem',
            type: 'pkcs1',
        },
    });
    return keys;
}
```

[Try it in Runkit](https://runkit.com/ericsnap/generate-ssh-key-for-putty-with-nodejs).

This generates keys that cannot be imported in `PuTTYgen`.

If we change the `cipher` to `aes128` they *can* be imported, but our security policy requires >128.

I have been unable to find lists of either what `crypto` can support and/or `PuTTY` can support...

Comment: Perhaps you can ask PuTTY to accept aes256 since *your* security policy requires it. Does your security policy understand that 2048 bit RSA is probably less secure than aes-128?

Comment: @JamesKPolk yeah, I don't control that. I am currently talking to Security so that our security story makes sense for all our internal users. I am by no means a security expert. I just implement the code and try make sure we don't shoot ourselves in the foot.

Comment: I was 3/4 serious. You *could* ask PuTTY to support aes-256 if that really is the problem, though that won't solve your immediate problem. I might have a look through the PuTTY source code to see what it can support.

Comment: I know you were ;)
But to be honest, the reason we are trying to get our keys to work with PuTTY is because we have internal users who use FileZilla for SFTP... And since the freeware version is now pretty much _malware_ I am working with IT (which is different from Security for our company...) to see what alternatives we have. One using a different client (which would support our SSH keys). Two, actually not using SFTP and use a shared storage (Sharepoint, OneDrive, Box, etc.).

Comment: Looking at Putty file `import.c`, it appears only AES-128 and Triple-DES are supported. It looks like it would require just a few lines of additional code to support aes-256-cbc, but, alas, it's not there yet.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yeah, thanks for looking into it. I did come across that `import.c` around the time I posted my question. Didn't give me a warm feeling. Working with IT and Security to come up with a compromise here.